# Function callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to Node.JS and I'm trying to callback a function and then display acc_token value on the web-page, but what I'm getting is "ReferenceError: acc_token is not defined at Object.handle".

Here is my code

```
app.get('/code/', function(request, response, callback) {
var code = request.query.code;
unirest.post('https://url/access_token')
.headers({
  'Accept': 'application/json'
})
.send({
  client_id: "#",
  client_secret: "#",
  code: code,
  redirect_uri: "#"
})
.end(function endReq(response, request) {
  parsedRes = response.body;
  acc_token = parsedRes.access_token
  console.log("Access token is:" + acc_token);
  return callback(acc_token);
});

response.send("Hello, " + code + "." + acc_token);
//
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try moving your `response.send` into the end callback function, otherwise it is called before the acc_token variable is declared, and also they are in different scope.

Comment: when i'm adding response.send to the end of my callback function i'm getting "Undefined is not a function" error on my response.send line...
If I completely remove response.send line I'm getting acc_token value on the webpage, but I need to use it further (i.e. write the value into the database). Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I thought it's not a really good idea to do so inside the endReq function...

Comment: that is because "response" is defined in app.get()'s callback and also the end() callback. Try renaming the one in end().

Comment: no luck, I renamed the response function but it didn't work...
I'll try to make it clear - the only thing I really need to do is to pass the acc_token value to my anonymous function (which is function(request, response, callback)) or to any other function. Is it possible?

Comment: no it is not possible in your case assuming `unirest.post()` is an asynchronous function. The line `response.send("Hello, " + code + "." + acc_token);` is being executed BEFORE the callback function in `end()`.